# Can't upgrade procps on 12.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, ipv6, proc

If I'm performing `apt-get upgrade` I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  procps
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/235 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 237, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 48, in main
    debs = apt_listchanges.read_apt_pipeline(config)
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/apt_listchanges.py", line 83, in read_apt_pipeline
    return map(lambda pkg: filenames[pkg], order)
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/apt_listchanges.py", line 83, in <lambda>
    return map(lambda pkg: filenames[pkg], order)
KeyError: 'procps'
Setting up procps (1:3.2.8-11ubuntu6.2) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript procps, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing procps (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 procps
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And `cat /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf /etc/sysctl.conf | sudo sysctl -p -` returns:

```
kernel.printk = 4 4 1 7
error: "net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr" is an unknown key
error: "net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr" is an unknown key
error: "Invalid argument" setting key "kernel.kptr_restrict"
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
error: "kernel.yama.ptrace_scope" is an unknown key
vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 0
```

Has anyone a clue what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

first try to rename your procps.conf as

```
sudo mv /etc/init/procps.conf /etc/init/procps.conf.old
```

if it works , well and good otherwise  last workaround is to download procps (1:3.3.3-2ubuntu7) and libprocps0 (1:3.3.3-2ubuntu7) then installing them manually.

You can download them from -

http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/procps

and

http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libprocps0

Updating them can fix the issue as mentioned here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/1157643 . its a well known bug , visit the link provided .

hope this time it will work.